# Table extending instead of creating

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bug in my excel sheet that appears on other computers I can't reproduce on my machine.

I made a sub that takes data from a database and create tables in Excel. In this case it's mining projects.

It picks the first cell, finds the first empty cell when going to the right, writes the header, makes a table with it then fill it with another sub.
When a coworker tries to use it, it extends the previous table then crashes while trying to make the new one, as two tables can't overlap.

Initial Layout:
[image: Initial layout]

What's supposed to happen:
[image: What's supposed to happen/ happens on my machine]

What my coworkers get:
[image: What my coworkers get]

```vb
Public Sub creerTable(Nom As Variant)
    
    Dim cellule As Range
    ' se placer
    Set cellule = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
    Do While cellule.Value <> "" Or Not IsEmpty(cellule)
        Set cellule = cellule.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop
    
    'cr?er le header
    cellule.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    cellule.Value = Nom
    
    'cr?er la table
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, cellule, , xlYes).Name = Nom
    
End Sub
```

EDIT: After more testing on my coworkers' computers, the problem is likely linked to an Excel setting. When something is written to the right of a table, the table extends to cover it. Googling revealed this to be an auto-correct behavior. I guess I'll have to deactivate that option of auto-correct.

Comment: Could it be your use of `Activesheet`. Are you certain the `Activesheet` is the one you are anticipating. Perhaps be more explicit there and do `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects.Add....`  Also, why the loop? `End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)` should already get you there, and any further attempt seems like "hoping". Alternatively you could do `Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(,1)` and definitely land on the last column.

Comment: Also.. What do you mean by "Extending". Your "Supposed to happen" screenshot shows more rows in the first table than your "Coworkers get" screenshot, so I'm not sure "Extending" is the right word, or I'm totally missing what's happening.

Comment: As you observe, tables cannot overlap so I am skeptical that this works on your computer. Is it possible that you can create a [mcve] which exhibits the behavior you describe (i.e., you can create an overlapping table without raising an error). Also, have you done any line-by-line debugging on coworker computers to see what (if anything) may be affecting it?

Comment: Also what's in columns A-R? If there are any empty headers in row 1, that might cause some problems also.

Comment: JNevill - I activate the right sheet before calling the function as it's supposed to be generic. The table creation would just crash on my computer too if I forgot it. The loop is necessary as the end method only exits the table for some reason.

Comment: David Zemens - I'm not creating an overlapping table on my computer… Also, no I haven't done line by line debugging on my coworker's computer. He kinda needs it to work. Columns A-R are filled with other 1 column tables.

Comment: *He kinda needs it to work.*  OK, so, you should debug it on his computer then, and figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: *I'm not creating an overlapping table on my computer…* Right. But why would the same code perform differently on your computer? It won't, unless there is some difference in the inputs. Are the tables filtered or sorted?Are there hidden rows that might contain blank values, etc. Put a `MsgBox cellule.Address` right before you do `cellule.Interior.Color` and let's see what it shows.

Comment: David Zemens - His computer I mean. My program is just a small timesheet application, not really worth interrupting him for that.

Comment: If you're not willing to debug your program on the machine which exhibits the failure, then you're just grasping at straws. It is impossible to say with much certainty what might be the problem, until you can recreate it. And if you can't recreate it on your machine, you need to do it on his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was really dumb. The problem is an autocorrect setting in excel. All I had to do was add this line:

```
Application.autocorrect.AutoExpandListRange = False
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how this code could possibly work on your machine, but not your co-workers. I suspect that the inputs must somehow be different, but that is for you (having access to the inputs, which we do not) to work out on your own. Generally: inconsistencies cannot exist, so when one appears to exist, examine your inputs and you'll usually find there is a discrepancy in the input data which causes the divergent output.

I'll note that The `End` method of range objects may not be reliable, in particular I observed things like `Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address` yields "B1" in the following scenario where column A, B and C are each separate `ListObject` tables:

[image]

And ALSO in this scenario:

[image]

It seems like you try to find the *next* empty cell/column (which may be between two or more non-empty cell/column). It *should* be trivial to do this, but we need to understand that *next* is relative to *what existing thing on your worksheet*?

Are you're trying to find the next empty cell *after* a `ListObject` named "Tâches" (or cell value = "Tâches")?

Comment: The input data is quite simple and the same for both me and my coworker. We open the file, specify the location of the database file, then click on an update button. As for the placement of my table, I simply go in the A1 cell, then go to the right until I find an empty cell. Row #1 is full of one column table headers. It just happens there's currently a hole between tâches and VIC.

Comment: @Eloyas do your tables have to been in a certain order? I.e. is it ok if the KOMET table gets added to the right of the VIC table?

Comment: @BigBen Order doesn't matter. It's just neater to have them all on a continuous row.